# How to refesh a directive on button click in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am familiar with how everything works in angular js,but i am very much new to custom directives in angular js. I am working on a library to upload file from client(angular js) to amazon s3..i have succesfully uploaded it but i am trying to rerender the directive on button click and i have no idea oh how to do it...please help..

```
angular.module('ngS3upload.directives', []).
  directive('s3Upload', ['$parse', 'S3Uploader', 'ngS3Config', function ($parse, S3Uploader, ngS3Config) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AC',
      require: '?ngModel',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: true,
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {

        $scope.emptyfile=function()
            {
            alert("hello");
            $scope.$apply();


            }; 
      }],
      compile: function (element, attr, linker) {
        return {
          pre: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            if (angular.isUndefined($attr.bucket)) {
              throw Error('bucket is a mandatory attribute');
            }
          },
          post: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // Build the opts array
            var opts = angular.extend({}, scope.$eval(attrs.s3UploadOptions || attrs.options));
            opts = angular.extend({
              submitOnChange: true,
              getOptionsUri: '/s3options',
              acl: 'public-read',
              uploadingKey: 'uploading',
              folder: '',
              enableValidation: true,
              targetFilename: null
            }, opts);


            {{ some code here}}

          }
        };
      },
      templateUrl: function(elm, attrs) {
        var theme = attrs.theme || ngS3Config.theme;
        return 'theme/' + theme + '.html';
      }
    };
  }]);
angular.module('ngS3upload').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('theme/bootstrap2.html',
    "<div class=\"upload-wrap\">\n" +  
    " <button class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"button\" ng-hide=\"filename\"><span ng-if=\"!filename\">Choose file</span></button>\n" +"<div id=\"imgdiv\" class=\"pindiv\" style=\"position: relative\" ng-if=\"filename\"><audio controls><source src=\"{{filename}}\" type=\"audio/ogg\"><source src=\"{{filename}}\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></audio><a href=\"\" value=\"change\" ng-click=\"emptyfile()\">Change</a></div>"+
    "<p></p><div class=\"progress\" ng-show=\"uploading\">\n"+"<div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\"{{progress}}\" aria-valuemin=\"2\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" style=\"width: {{progress}}%;\">\n"+"{{progress}}%"+" </div></div>\n"+
    "  <input type=\"file\" style=\"display: none\"/>\n"+
    "</div>"
  );


}]);
```

when i click on 'change' button which is returned from directive template,emptyfile() function is called and there i would like to re-render my directive.

Comment: If you want people to help you debug something, I suggest you try to reduce your code as much as you can to reproduce and isolate the problem. Is this truly related to S3 upload? Would the same work with mock `$timout`? Help us help you. :)

Comment: I have removed unecessary code.My question is not related to upload to s3.It is about how to re-render/refresh directive template when i click on a button that triggers 'emptyfile()' function from the code.I mean what should i write in emptyfile() function to refresh my directive template..I have searchrd in the internet but couldnt find an proper solution

Comment: What does "re-render" mean? What do you want to have happened after you click this button?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will enter a digest cycle when you click the button. If you code invoked the emptyFile() function already (i assume from your question everything works), and all you wish it to show a change in your directive,  simply make the elements in your directive dynamic.

You can apply styles, or hide / show elements using {{foo}} where foo is a scope variable.

```
$scope.foo = 'visible'

 $scope.emptyfile=function() {
        $scope.foo = 'hidden';
        // may be needed in case emtyfile is not part of digest cycle
        $scope.$apply()
 }
```

and in your temple:

```
<div style="{{foo}}"....
```